# Sign in with OAuth2 via firebase rest api getting Rejected

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to Sign in a user with OAuth2 via the firebase rest API, from google apps script. I'm using the [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) library and have  retrieved an access token with `service.getAccessToken()` ([see getAccessToken docs](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2#4-get-the-access-token)).

However when I post to the auth endpoint with the following code:

```
    var oAuthService= getOAuthService();
    const createUserWithOAuthUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=' + <API_KEY>
    const accessToken = oAuthService.getAccessToken()
    Logger.log(accessToken)
    const requestUri = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/' + SCRIPT_ID + '/usercallback'
    const payload = JSON.stringify({"postBody": "access_token=" + accessToken + "&providerId=google.com","requestUri":requestUri,"returnIdpCredential":true,"returnSecureToken":true})
    Logger.log(payload)
    const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(createUserWithOAuthUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
//        headers: {
//          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
//        },
        payload : payload
    });
```

I get this error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Failed to fetch resource from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo, http status: 401, http response: {\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 401,\n    \"message\": \"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.\",\n    \"status\": \"UNAUTHENTICATED\"\n  }\n}\n",
```

The OAuth process seems to go well as I go through the account selection/scopes review flow and get an authorized prompt.

I've followed the [firebase rest auth api docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential) and it looks like the way I'm doing this is correct, so I'm confused why it's being rejected. Any thoughts? Is there some way I can test the validity of my access_token? I've console logged it and it certainly looks token like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I just figured it out, it had to do with scopes.

Basically during the firebase sign in with OAuth process an automated call to the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo` api is made. This requires the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

I suppose firebase wanted specific user details to add to the user account. Not sure why it complained about tokens instead of scopes, definitely threw me off there!